# How can I apply multiple aggregation functions to the same column, with different groupby's?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm building some reporting in pandas, and I'd like to include comparisons to the overall values.

Let's say we have:

```
import pandas

data = {'puppy_name': ['Stanley', 'Doggo', 'Stanley', 'Doggo','Stanley', 'Doggo', 'Stanley', 'Doggo'],
'treats_earned': [25, 15, 20, 30, 20, 25, 20, 35],
'month': ['feb', 'feb', 'feb', 'feb','mar', 'mar', 'mar', 'mar']}

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to show something like:

```
pup     / month / pup_avg / overall_month_avg
Stanley | feb   | 22.5    | 22.5
Doggo   | feb   | 20      | 22.5
Stanley | mar   | 20      | 25
Doggo   | mar   | 27.5    | 25
```

So for one column we're grouping/meaning by ['month','pup'] and for the other we're grouping/meaning by ['month'].

Comment: And thank you! (-First-time, long-time)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC we need `groupby` twice and `map`

```
s=df.groupby(['puppy_name','month'])['treats_earned'].mean().reset_index()
s['overall_month_avg']=s['month'].map(df.groupby('month')['treats_earned'].mean())
s
Out[33]: 
  puppy_name month  treats_earned  overall_month_avg
0      Doggo   feb           22.5               22.5
1      Doggo   mar           30.0               25.0
2    Stanley   feb           22.5               22.5
3    Stanley   mar           20.0               25.0
```

Comment: Thank you! And is there a way I could have better explained (top-level) my question?

Comment: @juicero adding the rename